# JQuery Mobile word wrap on buttons using photo swipe

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I have a series of buttons containing images using the photoswipe plugin for Jquery mobile. Now, I have text in each one of these buttons (which are inside of the `.gallery li a`), but if the image is too small or the browser is made too narrow, the text simply goes outside of the viewing portion as the button gets smaller. I want to have it so that the text wraps and the button still encapsulates the text regardless. I've tried using `white-space:normal` and `word-wrap:break-word` to do this, but to no avail. Is there a way to do this other than having the text added to the image before loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use data-inline="true" within the anchor Inline makes the button as wide as the text inside of it needs to be but if you have a paragraph within a button then that may not be your solution it would be best to have a fixed width in that case so it wraps